# Scrapy pass value using meta never updated

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, python-requests, scrape

I was trying to scrape some websites. I already got the data and I tried to pass the value using `meta={}`. But the problem appears when I use `yield scrapy.Request` which goes to the next function. I was send to the next function is a new URL and using `meta` to pass the JSON value. I got new URL but not with JSON data, JSON never updated. Just passed the same values. I have no idea what's going on.

You can see my code, I was trying to pass the JSON values, but I got only the same JSON but the URL is updated with the new URL.

```
def first_function(self, response):
    value_json = self.get_json() #i got the json from here
    for key, value in value_json.items(): #loop the json
        for values in value:

            # values will show me as dictionay of dictionary
            # thats like {"blabla":{"key1":"value1","key1":"value2"}}
            # I gave the conditions as below to get just a value or to make sure if that key ("blabla") is exist
            # if the condition is true, i will get the value {"key1":"value1","key1":"value2"}

            if values == "blabla":
                get_url = "http://www.example.com/"
                yield Request(
                    url=get_url+values["id_url"],
                    meta={"data_rest":values}, 
                    callback=self.second_function
                )

def second_function(self, response):
    # ============== PROBLEM =====================
    # The problem is here!
    # I always got a new url from first_function, my logic is if I got a new url, i should get a new json
    # but the json or "data_rest" never updated. Always send the same json to this function
    # ============== PROBLEM =====================

    josn_data = response.meta["data_rest"]
    names = response.css() #get the tag in here
    for get_data in names:
        sub_url = get_data.css("a::attr(href)").extract()
        for loop_url_menu in sub_url:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=loop_url_menu, 
                headers=self.session,
                meta = {
                    'dont_redirect': True,
                    'handle_httpstatus_list': [302]
                }, callback=self.next_function
            )
```

Comment: Could it be related to the fact that you are only yielding a response when the condition is satisfied ( ```if values == "blabla":```) therefore meta is always ```{"data_rest":"blabla"}```?

Comment: what i mean is "blabla":{"data1":"value 1","data2":value 2"}. that is dictionary of dictionary. if i not give a condition like that. they will give me the key, value

Comment: Could you update the if condition in the question? - not 100% clear from this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news!!
I can solved it. we just have to append the value for the first after that we yield the value.

```
def first_function(self, response):
    temp = []
    value_json = self.get_json() #i got the json from here
    for key, value in value_json.items(): #loop the json
        for values in value:
            if values == "blabla":
                get_url = "http://www.example.com/"
                temp.append(values)

    yield Request(
        url=get_url+values["id_url"],
        meta={"data_rest":temp}, 
        callback=self.second_function
    )
```